# Perl regex variable for replacement count

Tags: regex, perl

For a simple use case as this one

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $text = "A choice between ASCII and UTF8 is simple";
$text =~ s/[[:upper:]]+/?/g;
```

I need to determine if a replacement was made or not. I am hoping to find a built in variable which would tell me that. It seems like there are lot's of variables available related to regex (e.g. $1, ... $', $&, @+, @- etc) but I haven't find one that can simply tell me whether a replacement was made or not or number of replacements made etc.

Sure I can save the original string and compare with the result though if this statistics is already available in one way or another I'd use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `s///` operator (without the `/r` flag) returns the number of replacements done, so you can simply do

```
if ($text =~ s/[[:upper:]]+/?/g) {
    # at least one replacement was done
} else {
    # nothing changed
}
```

[Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2F_PATTERN_%2F_REPLACEMENT_%2Fmsixpodualngcer)